# magento 1.9 - How I can diagnose the exception.log file

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I see this error on my exception.log, how I can diagnose or how I can find where is the issue?

```
2017-04-15T12:18:11+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Megamenu_Block_Megamenu' in /home/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('megamenu/megame...', Array)
#2 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('megamenu/megame...', 'leftmenu')
#3 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('megamenu/megame...', 'leftmenu')
#4 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#9 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(5, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#11 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: seems you have disabled module Megamenu and other module still use this module

Comment: and that is reason magento try to find out megamenu in Mage  namespace

Comment: search word "megamenu" in layout.xml files from app/design folder and fix it

Comment: No, the extension is not disabled

Comment: are you sure ?..

Comment: yes I just check again right now, and is enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the extension is not disabled

Then `megamenu/megamenu` is not the right block alias. Look in the extensions `etc/config.xml` for something like this:

```
<blocks>

    <megamenu>        <-- if this is different, `megamenu/megamenu` in the layout
                          XML files must be replaced with `somethingelse/megamenu`

        <class>Megamenu_Block_Megamenu</class>

    </megamenu>

</blocks>
```

Also, don't forget to clear the cache.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give permission for "megamenu/megamenu" block.
You can do this way;

in Admin Area,

**System/Permissions/Blocks**
add new block as "megamenu/megamenu"